# How to extract installed Apps on BlueStacks emulator

Tags: android, apk, bluestacks

I need to have open/edit/review of my own app which I've previously installed on BlueStacks.

Somehow I think there is a way to access what I looking for. Actually it's not a copyrighted product.

I've found the shortcut of this app which is in this path:

```
C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\Library\My Apps
```

When in looking for Target of this shortcut i found the name of project like `com.xxx.xxxx` and other things like these:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks\HD-RunApp.exe" -p net.xxxx.xxxxx -a net.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx
```

these x's refer to my application's name which is correct.

Comment: Hi, As i mentioned, This apk was installed before, i need to access the classes/src of this installed app on BlueStacks.

Comment: Ok do you have access to your apk file ? , I mean have you found the ***.apk in your computer ??

Comment: Of course not, dude..I knew how to DE-compile and these stuff. please read the question carefully. peace!

Comment: Then I think you need to edit your title ;)

Comment: y? i said "Installed App"..if you say so please give me better title to improve it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install any apk extracting app 'you can try [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en) for example'
, and then copy your apks to

> **sdcard > bstfolder > Documents**

follow [this](http://apkreview4u.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-get-apk-file-from-bluestacks-app.html) for full description

Comment: the example you mentioned worked, and now i gona say thank you.GOOD LUCK!

Comment: not working anymore. bstfolder is not there anymore.

Comment: /storage/sdcard/windows/documents worked for me, the file showed up in my documents

Answer (score 1):

Given answers no longer work for Bluestacks 4.
So if you are using Bluestacks 4 : use ES file manager and make a backup, same as before. Save it for instance in downloads.
Next in bluestacks go to Media Manager, downloads click on the backed up apk and click on export to windows. It'll let you pick a windows directory where you'll save the apk.

Answer (score -1):

You can Install '[ESFile Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Desfile%20explorer%20apk&pcampaignid=APPU_1_n0k4WK3mEIXfU4HUl4gO)' on your bluestacks then backup your installed app and copy them to:

> SDcard > Windows > BstSharedFolder

then you'll find it on windows on this folder:

> C: > ProgramData > BlueStacks > UserData > SharedFolder